# Filter the config dictionary based on user input - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a json config, based on user input, need to filter out the config and get only specific section. I tried running the code mentioned below, it returns the partially expected results.

Config:

```
superset_config = """
                [ {
                      "Area":"Texas",
                      "Fruits": { 
                                  "RED": {
                                           "Apple":["val1"],
                                           "Grapes":["green"]
                                         },
                                  "YELLOW": {"key2":["val2"]} 
                                }
                  },
                  {
                      "Area":"Dallas",
                      "Fruits": { 
                                    "GREEN": { "key3": ["val3"]} 
                                } 
                  }
                ]
                """
```

User Input:

```
inputs = ['Apple'] # input list
```

Code:

```
import json

derived_config = []
for each_src in json.loads(superset_config):
    temp = {}
    for src_keys in each_src:
        if src_keys=='Fruits':
            temp_inner ={}
            for key,value in each_src[src_keys].items():
                metrics = {key_inner:value_inner for key_inner,value_inner in value.items() if key_inner in inputs}
                temp_inner[key]=metrics
            temp[src_keys] = temp_inner
        else:
            temp[src_keys] = each_src[src_keys]
    derived_config.append(temp)
```

what do I get from above code:

```
derived_config= [
                    {'Area': 'Texas', 
                     'Fruits': {'RED': {'Apple': 'val1'}, 
                                'YELLOW': {}
                               }
                    }, 
                    {'Area': 'Dallas', 
                    'Fruits': {'GREEN': {}
                              }
                    }
                ]
```

what is needed: I need below results

```
derived_config= [
                    {'Area': 'Texas', 
                     'Fruits': {'RED': {'Apple': 'val1'}
                               }
                    }
                ]
```

can anyone please help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```py
import json

inputs = ['Apple'] # input list

derived_config = []
for each_src in json.loads(superset_config):
    filtered_fruits = {k: v for k, v in (each_src.get('Fruits') or {}).items()
                       if any(input_ in v for input_ in inputs)}

    if filtered_fruits:
        each_src['Fruits'] = filtered_fruits
        derived_config.append(each_src)

print(derived_config)
```

---

**Edit**: Based on the comments, it looks like you might want to filter the inner `Fruits` map based on the input list of fruits as well. In that case, we don't need to use the `any` function as above.

There is also an unintentional risk that we might mutate the original source config. For example, if you save the result of `json.loads(superset_config)` to a variable and then try to filter multiple fruits from it, likely it'll mutate the original config object. If you are directly calling `jsons.load` each time, then you don't need to worry about mutating the object; however you need to be aware that due to `list` and `dict` being mutable types in Python, this can be a concern to us.

The solution below does a good job of eliminating a possibility of mutating the original source object. But again, if you are calling `jsons.load` each time anyway, then you don't need to worry about this and you are free to modify the original config object.

```py
import json

# Note: If you are using Python 3.9+, you can just use the standard collections
# for `dict` and `list`, as they now support parameterized values.
from typing import Dict, Any, List


# The inferred type of the 'Fruits' key in the superset config.
#   This is a mapping of fruit color to a `FruitMap`.
Fruits = Dict[str, 'FruitMap']
FruitMap = Dict[str, Any]

# The inferred type of the superset config.
Config = List[Dict[str, Any]]


def get_fruits_config(src_config: Config, fruit_names: List[str]) -> Config:
    """
    Returns the specified fruit section(s) from the superset config.
    """

    fruits_config: Config = []
    final_src: Dict

    for each_src in src_config:
        fruits: Fruits = each_src.get('Fruits') or {}
        final_fruits: Fruits = {}

        for fruit_color, fruit_map in fruits.items():
            desired_fruits = {fruit: val for fruit, val in fruit_map.items()
                              if fruit in fruit_names}
            if desired_fruits:
                final_fruits[fruit_color] = desired_fruits

        if final_fruits:
            final_src = each_src.copy()
            final_src['Fruits'] = final_fruits
            fruits_config.append(final_src)

    return fruits_config
```

Usage:

```py
inputs = ['Apple'] # input list

config = json.loads(superset_config)
derived_config = get_fruits_config(config, inputs)

print(derived_config)
# prints:
#   [{'Area': 'Texas', 'Fruits': {'RED': {'Apple': ['val1']}}}]
```

Comment: thanks rv.kvetch. Can you help me understand the use of 'any' in above code?

Comment: also it does seem to be working for all cases. For ex: if I add one more entry under "RED" (added after your answer), it still returns all the values within matching block. for ex: in the above case it returns both Apple and Grapes ie -->  [{'Area': 'Texas', 'Fruits': {'RED': {'Apple': 'val1', 'Grapes': 'green'}}}], althrough only Apple is required based on your input. can you help?

Comment: The 'any' is a builtin function which in this case returns a boolean indicating whether the dictionary contains *any* of the keys we are looking for. As a specific example, given `inputs=['Apple', 'Orange']` it'll loop over each input and check if `derived_config[0]['Fruits']['RED']` contains at least an `Apple` or `Orange` key. Though from your last comment, I understand you might need a slightly modified solution, so the 'any' probably won't be needed here.

Comment: @Matthew I updated my answer based on the requested changes. hopefully that should now give the desired result.